# How to store storm tuple as parquet structure into hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-storm, parquet

I would like to persist tuples from storm bolt as parquet structure into hdfs.

1) Whats the best approach ?

2) Do I need to pre-create AVro/Protobuff schema for parquet so that tuple can create parquet structure correctly ?

3) Since I would like to use Spark for data analytics on parquet structures, should I store parquet into hdfs (as Spark plays nicely with Hdfs block) or storing parquet into any filesystem (S3 / Google Cloud) should be fine ?

4) It would be great if anyone can share example of storm tuple to parquet conversion, as I am not familiar with any parquet library which is compatible to storm tuples.

Thanks
Kaniska

Comment: You may follow [how spark does it](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetOutputWriter.scala), which is to use Hadoop `ParquetOutputFormat`